# Navigate between UIViewControllers and UISplitViewController

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ios7.1, ipad, xcode5.1

I have two `UIViewControllers` and a `UISplitViewController`. I am adding `UISplitViewController`  as root on 2nd `UIViewController`. Here is my code:

```
[splitViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav, detailNavigate, nil]];  
        [splitViewController setDelegate:detail];
        self.view.window.rootViewController=splitViewController;
```

With this code `UISplitViewController` gets added as root.Now from BACK button on SplitViewController. How to pop to Previous `UIViewController`? If I use this code, then `NavigationBarButton` on `UIViewController` does not work.

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:backToView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can i navigate to and from `UIViewControllers` ?

Comment: I just want to navigate between UIViewController and UISplitViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you should set `UINavigationController` as a window's rootviewcontroller and push `splitivewcontroller` on it.

e.g.,

```
[splitViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav, detailNaviagate, nil]];  
[splitViewController setDelegate:detail];
//self.view.window.rootViewController=splitViewController;
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:splitViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController; // make root a navigation controller
```

Now, if you push another view controller on the navigation stack, your back button should work.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You mean that i should add this to my appDelegate.Right?

Comment: Yes. It should be added to the appdelegate.

Comment: @ NeverHopeless,Ok.. One more thing please.When i need to call UISplitViewController by clicking a button in UIViewController,how should i do that.

Comment: What is meant by `call`, do you mean `push` splitcontroller ? then, try: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:instanceOfSliptcontroller Animated:YES]`

Comment: @ NeverHopeless. Yes i meant that. But it still showing in log that "  Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller "... What to do in this case??.. My apologies if i am disturbing you..

Comment: Do you want to show 2 uiviewcontrollers first and them display splitcontroller ?

Comment: yes,Exactly and navigate between them.Provide me a solution